# VBA Adding a button that adds a row that copies the formulas in a certain from above the activecell, not working

Tags: vba, insert, row

I want to make a button that copies a certain formulas within a range, and inserts it below the activecell. 
It works, but now the formula reference keeps linking to the formula above it, I need it to act like an AutoFill,

```
Sub Rijen_Toevoegen()

ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1 & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Formula = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use autofill like this:

```
Sub Rijen_Toevoegen()

    ActiveCell.Offset(1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row + 1)

End Sub
```

Look that the destination range must include the ActiveCell's row `"B" & ActiveCell.Row` and also the row you are filling `":H" & ActiveCell.Row + 1` (plus 1)

Let me know if it works

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly, I already tried the:"
AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row) " But I thought i had to add .Formula after this like this:

Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row).AutoFill Destination:=Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).formula

Answer (score 0):

Offset should be used like this:

```
currentSheet.yourRange.Offset(offsetRow, offsetColumn)
```

With that, you should change your code to:

```
Sub Rijen_Toevoegen()
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row + 1 & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row + 1).Formula = Range("B" & ActiveCell.Row & ":H" & ActiveCell.Row).Formula
End Sub
```

Also, it is recommended to avoid using .Select, .Active, ActiveCell and the likes.